# Instagram API - Get only images from a feed

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to create a request which can retrieve only photos (not videos) from an Instagram feed.
Sure, I can download all feeds and then filter them on the client side, but I want to get the data already filtered.

Is it possible?

Comment: Looking at the API it doesn't look like it support it.

Comment: Fixed some grammar and formatting. Removed the meaningless thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything in the API that supports it.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me.

```
foreach ($pictures as $picture) {
  if($picture->data->type === "image"){
      // your code here
  }
}
```

**$pictures** is the return of instagram api

return example:

```
pagination: {}
data:   
    0:  
    id: ""
   user:    {…}
   images:  {…}
   created_time:    ""
   caption: {…}
   user_has_liked:  false
   likes:   {…}
   tags:    […]
   filter:  "Nashville"
   comments:    {…}
   type:    "image" // this one!
   link:    ""
   location:    null
   attribution: null
   users_in_photo:  []
meta:   
  code: 200
```

Hope this helps.